# What is this grey button on the New Nintendo 3DS XL?

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

There is a grey button-like thing on the right side of the New Nintendo 3ds XL. It is above the main <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> buttons:

[image: New Nintendo 3DS XL button]

Specifically, it's on the bottom half of the system, next to the screen, straight above the <kbd>Y</kbd> and diagonal to the <kbd>X</kbd> button. I used to have a normal 3DS, but I don't think this ever existed on it.

It looks like a button, but I'm not sure. What is it and what does it do?

Answer (score 8):

As per the [Nintendo site](https://www.nintendo.com/3ds/new-nintendo-3ds/) there is this image that explains the button. They call it the 'C stick'.

[image: New Nintendo 3DS XL - 'New controls' website]

> ## New controls
>
> The C stick brings new control possibilities (like intuitive camera control) to compatible games.